# Spring data rest link name

Tags: rest, spring-data-rest

I have a class Category which has multiple bi-directional many-to-one association with other entities-

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @TableGenerator(name = Category.TABLE_NAME, table = "LMC_GENERATED_KEYS", pkColumnName = "ID", valueColumnName = "LAST_VALUE", pkColumnValue = Category.TABLE_NAME, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = Category.TABLE_NAME)
    private Long categoryId;


    // bi-directional many-to-one association to LmcCategoryImage
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "categoryImage")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private CategoryImage categoryImage;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to LmcCategoryProductXref
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryProductXref")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<CategoryProductXref> categoryProductXrefs;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to LmcCategoryXref
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryxref", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<CategoryXref> categoryxrefs;

}
```

This has been exposed as repository via below repository.

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Category, Long> {

}
```

This repository generates following json-

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated": true
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "activeEndDate": "2014-11-25T04:40:52.000+0000",
        "activeStartDate": "2014-11-25T04:40:37.000+0000",
        "archived": false,
        "createdBy": "SYSTEM",
        "modifedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "dateCreated": "2014-11-25T04:40:37.000+0000",
        "dateModified": "2014-11-25T04:40:37.000+0000",
        "description": "DESCRIPTION",

      },
      "categoryImage": null,
      "categoryProductXrefs": [

      ],
      "productFeatureds": [

      ],
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001"
        },
        "categoryXrefs": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/categoryXrefs"
        },
        "parentCategory": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/parentCategory"
        },
        "categoryAttributes": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/categoryAttributes"
        },
        "productProductFeatured": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/productProductFeatured"
        },
        "categoryProductFeature": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/categoryProductFeature"
        },
        "categoryImage": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/categoryImage"
        },
        "categoryProductXref": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/categoryProductXref"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
"page": {
  "size": 20,
  "totalElements": 1,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "number": 0
}
```

In this json all _link have been created automatically because I have mapped by relation ship in this entity.

These urls have been generated as camel case based on given attributes name. Is there any way, I can override these name and give my own customize name like  categoryImage as categoryimg and categoryProductXref as categoryproductxref

Answer (score 3):

Putting @RestResource annotation in my base resource entity class did the trick for me:

```
@RestResource(rel = "usertype", path = "usertypes")
    private List<Usertype> userTypes;
```

So:

```
"_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
},
"userTypes": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/userTypes"
}
```

}

Becomes:

```
"_links": {
"self": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1"
},
"usertype": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/usertypes"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

(Not enough reputation to add a comment).  Had you tried just

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "fkCategoryImage" )
@JsonManagedReference
@RestResource(rel="mycategoryimage")
private CategoryImage categoryImage;
```

So omit the 'path' part of the RestResource. That successfully names the _link for me and the URL is navigable

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? I'm guessing but I reckon that changing the property might also cause the links to be renamed

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to LmcCategoryProductXref
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryProductXref")
@JsonManagedReference
@JsonPropertyName("categoryproductxrefs")
private Set<CategoryProductXref> categoryProductXrefs;
```

Comment: @JsonPropertyName is not available in classpath because I am using spring data rest which uses jackson-annotations. I tried @ JsonProperty but it also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I see that I can use    `@RestResource(path="mycategoryimage" ,rel="mycategoryimage" )`

```
// bi-directional many-to-one association to LmcCategoryImage
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "fkCategoryImage" )
    @JsonManagedReference
    **@RestResource(path="mycategoryimage" ,rel="mycategoryimage" )**
    private CategoryImage categoryImage;
```

It generates url which I want.

```
"mycategoryimage": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/lmc-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/mycategoryimage"
},
```

But this URL is not  working showing blank page. If I remove @RestResource and create a Repository which represent CategoryImage entity like below.

```
 @RepositoryRestResource(path = "/mycategoryimage")
    public interface CategoryImageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CategoryImage, Long> {

    }
```

Spring data rest generate a Url and work perfectly but it is still in camel case.

```
"categoryImage": {
"href": "http://localhost:8080/letmecall-persistence/jpa/categories/10001/categoryImage"
}
```